# BTree Implementation - Do I need to know the order of the tree first?

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

So I have a project for my Data structures class and I have to implement a very simple information database. The records have to be stored in a file, and when the program is opened - they have to be read from the file and put in a BTree. My problem is that we still haven't talked about BTrees and the lecture in the course book isn't too clear (it doesn't have any code, just explanations and a few examples).

My question is: Can I create a BTree without knowing its order first? Or should I just set a very high number for the order, so that I can be sure it would be able to fit a lot of records? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can -- BTrees are designed to sort their input.  All that's needed is the ability to compare any two of your objects, and be able to determine which one is "larger" or should go later.  BTrees grow dynamically as you add more items to them, growing more levels to them.  I hope your professor covers BTrees well, as they are a fascinating structure :-).

If you're expected to implement a BTree as part of your assignment, you'll need to go to the TA's and make them explain it in detail -- the general idea is that each node is a either one that has values in it, sorted, or one that points to other nodes, based on ranges of values.  Every time you add a node to this tree, you walk down to where the node should be, and add the node, if possible.  If not, you reorganize the tree until it is possible, and then add the node.

The devil's in the details, and the details in this case will take some time, and good explanation, to fully grok.  The reason people put up with the headache all the complexity causes is because BTrees don't need to know in advance how big they'll ultimately be, or what range the elements will cover, or anything else.  As a bonus, they're very well suited to be used on disk, where you can't even store all the elements in memory.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do it? I mean, how should I build a BTree if I don't know what the maximum order will be? Do I have to make constant checks whether the entries are in their place or?

Comment: Go schedule a TA session, if possible.  Textbooks are horrible at explaining these sorts of things.  Absolutely horrible.  Which language are you best with?

Comment: The course is in C++, so I guess a C++ btree would help.

Comment: Heh, if I were you, I'd really recommend looking for a python BTree implementation, first, as you won't be able to read the C++ version -- memory management details will make you go crazy.

Comment: Yes, but my project has to be done in C++. THe idea is to create just a simple BTree implementation that would be able to store all of the file records. But since I don't know how many records there are, how many records will be added/removed during runtime, I just wanted to know if I could create a BTree without knowing its order. And I was wondering for just a sample implementation. Most of the implementations that I've seen come from libraries which are pretty complex and have dozens of features that I'm not going to need or use.

Comment: Yep -- this is where you make the professor (or his TA's) earn their pay.  If you are told you should be able to implement a BTree, they should have (or should help you catch up in a hurry) given you what you need to do that.  Copying another library's BTree won't do what you're looking for, as the goal here is for you to learn how to implement and use a data structure.  Don't let the professor get away with doing half a job...

Comment: The problem is that the structure will be explained, but we are behind schedule. The deadline will pass before we are able to take the material. The thing is that he can't extend it because the material for only one of 15 projects isn't taught in lectures. That's why I need help. He did say to the other students that have the same projects that they can use a BTree library, but I want to do it by myself, even though it will be quite simpler.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your own BTree then you should make sure that it can support different orders, specifically because the order that you want to use will depend on the medium.  The purpose of a BTree is to minimize the time it takes to do random accesses, so an in-memory BTree (if you were to use it that way) would want a single node to fit in a cache line, and if you are going to be storing the BTree on disk (which you will be doing in this case) you will want your nodes to fit in a disk sector.